# Signing a 0x limit order as a taker without UI

Tags: 0x

I have been using the @0x/contract-wrappers to sign a limit order as the taker but I can't find a way to configure a provider that can accept a private key to sign the order rather than using Metamask through the browser. Does anybody have any advice on how to "take" a limit order using a headless server?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The following guide is only for “making” orders, not “taking” orders. Apologies for the confusion.

This gist is a guide on how to create, hash, sign, fill, get state, and cancel a 0x v4 RFQ order. Note that the method of signing an order is the same for limit orders (/orderbook) and RFQ orders (/swap), just the payload is different: https://gist.github.com/PirosB3/8141b51fbb307bca265866ef1cef564f

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to sign anything to take/fill a limit order. As a taker, you pass in the order and the signature (both created by the maker) to `fillLimitOrder()` on the Exchange Proxy.

Signing transactions with a private key depends on what library you're using. If you are using 0x providers, you can use the [`PrivateKeyWalletSuprovider`](https://github.com/0xProject/tools/blob/development/subproviders/src/subproviders/private_key_wallet.ts#L22) as part of a `Web3ProviderEngine`. If you're using ethers, create a [`Wallet`](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/#Wallet-constructor) signer with the private key. If you're using `web3js` you can call [`web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add()`](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/#Wallet-constructor)`.

Comment: Hi Lawrence. Thanks for taking the time to reply. This is the code I was following:

  const exchange = new ContractWrappers.IZeroExContract(
    addresses.exchangeProxy,
    supportedProvider
  );

  const tx = await exchange
    .fillLimitOrder(order, signature, new BigNumber(order.takerAmount))
    .callAsync();
}

In the example the supportedProvider is Metamask.  I have been using ethers.js Wallet to sign transactions, but this doesn't seem to be the correct type to pass in as a supportProvider. I will look into the PrivateKeyWallerSubprovider if that is the way to go.